# Typescript union item sibling property not inferred

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

How is it possible to make typescript return the full correct type for a given element? It does not correctly infer the sibling properties

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAAhGMHsDsGcBcS3ACwKYFsCGIC8IBvUMEGNAeQDMAuEAbWJMMaZAAcAnSNgRloPZdefEACIAgqIA0g7jwBMtBSAC+Ulk07dFhWW3kjRPUao2r1rZpbBbe-PT0MAhEyrNumAXWIqQWWBAwCADcwMTI6NgAdGRUUdhsABSIuAB8ViQsAJaUyVG2PPlCjni4+BKiAJRElvBFcvW88qX4CsEgAPQdIADmHGhYiLCQIJRYHGZ1tvLtXSDwAdCQiChYbGwAniweqpVAA)

```js
  const schema = {
    oneOf: [
      {
        prop1: { prop11: "A", prop12: 12 },
        prop2: { prop21: "1" }
      },
      {
        prop1: { prop11: "B" }
      }
    ]
  } as const;

  schema.oneOf.map(t => {
    
    if(t.prop1.prop11 === "A"){
      t.prop1.prop12 === 12; // great so far
      t.prop2; // ts not happy
    }
  })
```

Comment: `as const` makes TS infer most narrow type. Drop it and you'll get your `.prop2`

Comment: I don't think TS can "backtrack" in this way. When you do `t.prop1.prop11 === "A"` it infers that `prop12: 12` but wont infer anything for  the root item. You can confirm this [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/ATDGHsDsGcBdmqAFgUwLYENgF5gG8AoEEKFAeQDMAuYAbSOJEMcaQ2gBUB3cG2AJwCuKADQMWwAA79wkgIw08UmfIXAARAEF1I5bLkAmGoeABfMRJDTZR-HskG16uerPji590y+XW7brzAFBgANtCiBD6+VipqStaqNOoAQq6mPumMALoMpsDsYFBwANyRIIiomAB0pJRVmJIAFPDYAHz4ZcQAlhTNVWycPACUzCywVQlyE7EGONi4hsXAAPTLwADm-CgY8NDgQRj8PuMJBkurwLDQwJDg8GySkgCe7plmQ0A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by two ways

1)

```
const schema1 = {
  oneOf: [
    {
      prop1: { prop11: "A", prop12: 12 },
      prop2: { prop21: "1" }
    },
    {
      prop1: { prop11: "B" }
    }
  ]
} as const;

schema1.oneOf.map(t => {
  if (t.prop1.prop11 === "A") {
    t.prop1.prop12 === 12; // great so far
    if ("prop2" in t) {
      t.prop2.prop21; // TypeScript infers correct type
    }
  }
});
```

Another one if you don't want to use if condition

```
interface TypeA {
  type: "a";
  prop1: { prop11: "A"; prop12: number };
  prop2: { prop21: string };
}

interface TypeB {
  type: "b";
  prop1: { prop11: "B" };
}

type Schema = TypeA | TypeB;

const schema2: Schema = {
  type: "a",
  prop1: { prop11: "A", prop12: 12 },
  prop2: { prop21: "1" }
};

schema2.prop1.prop12 === 12; // great so far
schema2.prop2.prop21; // TypeScript infers correct type
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=42&ssc=56&pln=22&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBBwAsCmBbAhgRhgXhgbwCgYZwkB5AMwC4YBtI4-BxmABwCcRWMa83PuPGACIAgsIA0-LhgBMNOTAC%20E5ow5d5%20aa1lDhGYcrUq1hFsQ3deOjPoBCRpSYYBdAkphoIMUJCgA3AQE8MjoGAB0pJQR6KwAFLDYAHxMxACWFDCJEVaReVjYRSLiAJRpjFC5Avk1sjjFcgEwAPQtMADm7EhosBAgMBRo7GqZ2cJWskbpYDBQ5eYWVZPVmhjNbTAAKgCerEgAysDs6aywMxRI7D6g7N3AsFB7SC7EzkqlQQQzUFdDwEhts9RBUnvsaMI0MIgpYajYChDxM08lowABXFAAIyuyhhOi0fEmQmgJzAHVxHmCPz%20aABQP29lBzwhmOhDDy8JqDicQWcBDBgKOYTQOHpSBBAB8xfYvn5oHBEKg0FohUrRYsBRCoapYTJOTJ9OIpCiFPVTLrdPrdPpDMYlF9QkrZKtuC7FEVcE1Wu0uj0%20gMhiNHehnSsiRt2rt9kcTmcYBcrjcQHckA85s8gA)

Answer (score 1):

You can [discriminate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#discriminated-unions) by the presence/absence of a unique top-level property using the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in):

> Ref: TS Handbook: [The `in` operator narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing)

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBBwAsCmBbAhjAvDA3gKBhnCQHkAzALhgG0DDc76YAHAJxGYEYqcX2vuMAEQBBIQBo+HTgCYqsmAF9xjemw5zcU5jMFDOQpSqbLV+JoXVce2znoBCh0yeMwAunkUw0EGKEhQANx4ePDI6AB0xOQR6MwAFLCYAHwMhACWZDDxQlYyhulgMFAAlGn0UBFWnFX8sqoWMAD0TQB6APyqlXmqLR10XkgANhBI5YTddb1tnYSKniXBQA)

```ts
schema.oneOf.map(t => {
  if ("prop2" in t) {
    t.prop1.prop12
          //^? (property) prop12: 12
    t.prop2
    //^? (property) prop2: { readonly prop21: "1"; }
  } else {
    t.prop1
    //^? (property) prop1: { readonly prop11: "B"; }
  }
});
```